# Not Sure Why I'm Getting A Template Parsing Error

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

so I'm fairly new to Spring Boot and thymeleaf and I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a template parsing error but only when the form input is invalid. i.e I go to /register leave the form blank and click the submit button. As I've annotated my UserAccount classes private variables with @NotBlank it's invalid. Thus, the form should redisplay with the errors. But it doesn't and I get a template parsing error. I'd imagine the problem is in the html. What have I done wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="layouts :: header"></head>
<body>
    <nav th:replace="layouts :: navigation"></nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form th:action="@{/notes/register}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" th:field ="${user.username}"/>
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}" class="alert alert-danger">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" th:field="${user.email}"/>
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}" class="alert alert-danger">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" th:field="${user.password}"/>
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}" class="alert alert-danger">
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>





@GetMapping("/register")
public String getRegisterPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new UserAccount());
    return "security/register";
}

@PostMapping("/register")
public String postRegisterPage( @Valid UserAccount user, BindingResult results) {
    if(results.hasErrors()) {
        return "security/register";
    }
    userRepo.save(user);
    return "redirect:/notes";
}
```

Error:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Mar 12 21:20:34 GMT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/security/register.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/security/register.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "security/register" - line 12, col 40)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "security/register" - line 12, col 40)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide the full stack trace of the template parsing error (as formatted text). The stack trace should identify the line in the template which is causing the error.

Comment: @andrewjames yeah it's line 12 but I don't know whats wrong with it <input type="text" id="username" th:field ="${user.username}"/>

Comment: Thank you for the update - but you should still [edit] your question to provide the full stack trace of the template parsing error (as formatted text). And, at the same time,you can  include that specific line in the question (instead of in a comment, where relevant details like that tend to get a bit lost).

Comment: When you use `th:object="${user}"`, that means that Thymeleaf expressions in child elements no longer need to refer to `user`. Instead you can use `*{username}` - note the [use of the asterisk](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax). I am not saying this is the solution, but worth bearing in mind.

Comment: @andrewjames thank you, that worked. I wasn't aware of that and I've noted to post the full stack trace anymore.

Comment: I am surprised that fixed your problem. Both notations are supposed to be usable together. Just because you have `th:object="${user}"` - that should not stop you from using `${user.username}`. It just means you can _also_ use `*{username}`, if you want to.

Comment: @andrewjames yeah, my bad, false alarm. I checked it on a different form by mistake. I've update the question with the error.

Comment: Questions relating to this error have been asked (and answered) several times on Stack Overflow: [Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean available](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Neither+BindingResult+nor+plain+target+object+for+bean+name+available). Have you researched these?

Comment: I'm currently doing so. Haven't come across anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't specified the name of the model attribute. Spring assumes the name of the model attribute is the same as the class unless otherwise specified so on changing the code to the following it worked

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String postRegisterPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") UserAccount user, BindingResult results) {
    if(results.hasErrors()) {
        return "security/register";
    }
    userRepo.save(user);
    return "redirect:/notes";
}
```